# Tumblr: {ReblogURL} keeps putting web address before the correct URL. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-themes

**I'm coding a tumblr theme and I added a button on each post for the a Reblog option next to the date and note count. The html looks like this:**

**Note: Apologies for the lack of url's I'm new to StackO and was not allowed to include them**

```
<footer class="post-foot hover-class">
{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}" class="notes-post-date">{TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}{block:NoteCount} <span class="note-date-divider">/</span> <a href="{Permalink}" class="notes-post-date">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}{block:NoteCount} <span class="note-date-divider">/</span> <a href=“{ReblogURL}” target=“_blank” class=“details”>Reblog</a>{/block:NoteCount}
</footer>
```

The issue is that when clicking the *Reblog* button it links you to the correct url to reblog but always places the website's original address in front of the whole reblog URL in front of it.

So instead of getting: *[correct reblog url]*

You're getting: *[website url]/[reblog url]*

**Is there a way I could change the html omit the beginning website url or just fix this in  any way?**

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own question. The issue was that the {reblogURL} was in quotations thus adding the existing website's url in automatically as a prefix